# Configure method startup.cs asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

When i request to the page. Why can't debug in configure method in file startup.cs?

Are configure method run only once when application start?

Comment: What's the content in `Configure` and what you want to debug? For `Configure` method itself, it will only run once since it is only used to configure the request pipeline. There is no need to run `Configure` method once the pipeline is but. For `Request the page`, it will go through the `Middleware` one by one instead of `Configure` method, in general, if you want to debug request, you need to debug `Middleware` instead of `Configure` method. You could check [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Configure method in the Startup class of an ASP.NET Core application executes once at application start-up.  It configures the middleware components that control how your app will respond to HTTP requests.

More information on this method can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.1

And here's a nice overview of the ASP.NET Core startup process: https://developer.telerik.com/featured/understanding-asp-net-core-initialization/